# Python list from reader

Tags: python, list

New to Python so help much appreciated. Trying to create a list from a csv file but I get back empty list. The code is:

```
f = open('f04.csv','r')
fs = csv.reader(f)

for row in fs:
    print(row)

print("\n create list:")
rawlist = list(fs)
print(rawlist)
```

The output is

```
['0.161872459', '0.007599374', '0.356000303']
['0.252876406', '0.174271357', '0.186588529']
['0.002431561', '0.304828772', '0.413916445']
['0.317126652', '0.205842315', '0.007455314']
['0.035314146', '0.033238938', '0.037165931']
['0.701855497', '0.173086947', '0.040612888']
['0.576945162', '0.846018396', '0.046673223']
['0.170591115', '0.587155632', '0.177219448']
['0.83711092', '0.419058334', '0.829849144']

 create list:
[]
```

As you can see the reader works but when I try to create a list it returns empty. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators such as files can only be iterated once. You need to re-initialize them to be able to restart reading from the beginning. Try:

```
f = open('f04.csv','r')
fs = csv.reader(f)

rawlist = []
for row in fs:
    print(row)
    rawlist.append(row)

print(rawlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only move though the iterator once. You can however *reset* the iterator by using `seek` (see docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek).

Your example would then only need **one additional line** of code, becoming:

```
f = open('f04.csv','r')
fs = csv.reader(f)

for row in fs:
    print(row)

f.seek(0)

print("\n create list:")
rawlist = list(fs)
print(rawlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Files cannot be iterated twice without rewinding, and `csv.reader` returns an iterator that cannot be iterated twice at all.

The easy and "right" way is that you load the whole file into memory:

```
with open('f04.csv') as f:   # with syntax ensures that the file is closed right away
    rawlist = list(csv.reader(f))

# from here on, `rawlist` contains everything you had in the file

for row in rawlist:
    print(row)

print(rawlist)
```

This will work as long as your file is not huge.